# Apache share directories in whm

Tags: apache, directory, virtual, shared

I have a whm server 
(CENTOS 6.7 x86_64 kvm –  WHM 56.0 (build 18))
I want to share a folder to all the websites I host

The folder I want to share is located here
/home3/all_files

I want to make the folder in each website all_files
so if I had an image in the all_files folder it can be acccess via the web at
http://examplesite.com/all_files/1.jpg
and
http://examplesite2.com/all_files/3.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Are you feeling comfortable with the console?

I am an old school person and will solve that problem with old and proven 'ln' utility:

```
ln -s /var/www/examplesite.com/all_files /home3/all_files
ln -s /var/www/examplesite2.com/all_files /home3/all_files
```

and so on.

You'll have a symbolic link to the /home3/all_files directory for your websites, no WHM involved. Both your websites will have access to that directory.

You will need to be aware of file locking and such still!